# Button theme works with RaisedButton (deprecated) but not witn ElevatedButton

Tags: flutter

When I use `buttonTheme` it works with RaisedButton.

```
buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
  buttonColor: Colors.green.withAlpha(125),
),
```

But since RaisedButton is deprecated it does not work with ElevatedButton. So how to use it for ElevatedButton?

Comment: check [ElevatedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html) and [New Buttons and Button Themes](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons) in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have an `elevatedButtonTheme` property :

```
elevatedButtonTheme : ElevatedButtonThemeData(
  // ...
),
```